# MySQL 8.0 Centroid Query

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to pull a centroid from a field called "coordinates" which is of type "polygon" like this:

```
SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(coordinates)))) 
FROM contract 
WHERE address = '0x44145867fA5c74Fa3fC9b7a8d6c495e40c6BB3ED' 
LIMIT 1
```

This is throwing me the following error:

> Error Code: 3055. Geometry byte string must be little endian.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think you should call `ST_AsText()`. `ST_Centroid()` expects the argument to be a geomery value, not text.

Comment: If you want to display the result as text, I think it should be `ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(...))`